# How to set a wide resonator spread radius for a portal?

Tags: ingress

I noticed that portals have different resonator spread radius and it does not seem it depends on the level of resonators. The further resonators apart the more difficult it is for enemies to take over the portal

**How can I make sure I get the biggest spread radius possible?**

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Resonator distance from the portal center is determined by your distance when you place the resonator. Stand 50m away from the portal and the resonators will be 50m. Stand 1m and the resonators will be 1m away.

When using the "deploy" button without selecting a resonator slot, it will select one of the open direction slots and deploy there. I believe it begins with the one closest to you, but I'm not 100% certain

Comment: Have you done some tests or is it from the internet?

Comment: @BanditoBunny both

Comment: I confirm, resonators are placed where you stand when adding it

Comment: @CédricJulien They are not placed where you stand when you add one. I stood in the same spot, without gps floating about, and placed 8 resonators, creating a normal circle. They are placed in the compass directions around the portal at the distance you are standing when placing them, meaning that if you don't move and one happens to be placed exactly where you are, another of the 8 will be twice as far from you as the portal.

Comment: Just to clarify, you can't stand more than 35m away; otherwise the portal will be out of range.

Comment: @Alok: I think you can stand 40m away from a portal. I have several portals where the resonators are 36, 37 and 38m away. The Ingress Portal Attack Simulator lets you place them 40m away, therefore I guess the max. distance is 40.

Comment: Just a check, is this still accurate?  I didn't actually have to walk all the way around the outer edge of the action radius to place the resonators, I could have just stood at the one nearest my car and pressed the button eight times? :/ oh well, walking is good for me...

Comment: @gatherer818 It's still accurate. You've never needed direction, only distance.

Comment: @Daenyth thanks for your quick reply.  There are three unclaimed portals near me - the majority of the portals in my little area - and that will help me move quite a bit faster on my excursion today.

Comment: The direction aspect used to be more clear when you needed to select the slot, there was no bare "deploy" button.